# How do I regex match these 3 scenarios?

Tags: regex

I have a lot of automations running some Azure deployment commands and I need to support values wrapped with quotes and none at all. It needs to support lookahead and lookbehind. It's running in Powershell so is supported.

I can extract examples 1 and 2 OK but not the 3rd without running a condition and separate regex after every capture. How would I match this in the one query?

Current Regex : https://regex101.com/r/qgX6aQ/1 : `(?<= --resource-group ['"])(.*?)(?=['" ])`

In this example I need to extract `RGName` :

1. `az vm create --resource-group "RGName" --name 'VMName'`
2. `az vm create --resource-group 'RGName' --name VMName`
3. `az vm create --resource-group RGName --name "VMName"`

Comment: try this: (?<= --resource-group )(['"]?)([\w-]+)\1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the match you don't need a lookbehind, you can just match it.

You could use a named capture group, for example `value`. To match the opening single or double quote with a closing single or double quote, you can also use a capturing group with a backreference `\1`

The pattern either matches from an opening till closing single or double quote, or matches any char except a whitespace char or single and double quote.

The space at the end is also not mandatory.

```
--resource-group (?:(["'])(?<value>.*?)\1|(?<value>[^\s"']+))
```

**Explanation**

- `--resource-group`  Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(["'])` Capture **group 1**, match either `"` or `'`
  - `(?<value>.*?)` Named group *value*, match any char except a newline, as least chars as possible
  - `\1`  Backreference to group 1, match the previously matched `"` or `'`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<value>[^\s"']+)` Named group *value*, match 1+ occurrences of any char except a whitespace or `"` or `'`
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=--resource-group+%28%3f%3a%28%5b%22%27%5d%29%28%3f%3cvalue%3e.*%3f%29%5c1%7c%28%3f%3cvalue%3e%5b%5e%5cs%22%27%5d%2b%29%29&i=az+vm+create+--resource-group+%22RG-P-NETWORK02%22+--name+%22VMName%22%0d%0aaz+vm+create+--resource-group+%22RGName%22+--name+%27VMName%27%0d%0aaz+vm+create+--resource-group+%27RGName%27+--name+VMName%0d%0aaz+vm+create+--resource-group+RGName+--name+%22VMName%22%0d%0aaz+vm+create+--resource-group+%27RGName%27%0d%0a%0d%0aaz+vm+create+--resource-group+%27RGName%22+--name+VMName%0d%0aaz+vm+create+--resource-group+%22RGName%27+--name+VMName%0d%0aaz+vm+create+--resource-group+%27RGName+--name+VMName)

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you. Gave you the answer as it gave me a different approach to solving the problem. My answer gives the same result but I've now learnt how to use named matches and back referencing. Thanks again.

Comment: Just for extra info and considering I'm using Powershell, it can be accessed like this : `[regex]::Matches($Command, "--resource-group (?:([`"`'])(?<value>.*?)\1|(?<value>[^\s`"`']+))").groups | where {$_.name -eq "value"} | select -ExpandProperty Value`

Comment: I've been playing around with your regex. Is there any benefit or difference in using it like this? `--resource-group (?:(["'])?(?<value>.+?)([\s"']))`

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle the three cases separately:

```
(?<= --resource-group (
  '(.*?)(?=')
  |
  "(.*?)(?=")
  |
  (\w*)
  )
)
```

Comment: I would prefer this approach too since it's super clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Just tried and receive this error for that combination : "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width"

Comment: Good luck with it. :)

Comment: This has been in the back of my mind for a long time and most things I've tried produce the same error. Just now I thought of moving the character match outside of the lookbehind and this looks like it works : (?<= --resource-group )['"]?(.*?)(?=['" ])

Answer (score 0):

This has been in the back of my mind for a long time and most things I've tried produce the same error `"A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width"`.

Moving the character match outside of the lookbehind looks like it works :

`(?<= --resource-group )['"]?(.*?)(?=['" ])`

I'm still happy to take suggestions and improvements on this.